# remove a particular filename from the output of for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have various files date wise as:

> cpms_2015_09_01.txt
>
> lms_2015_07_10.txt
>
> kmps_2015_10_07.txt
>
> lmps_2015_10_07.txt
>
> cpmgs_2015_10_07.txt

I wanted to remove from the **"for loop"** files of today's date name
How can I do this, I wrote a code for which I can store the file paths of all files in:

```
XCOUNT_1=D:\check\cpms_2015_09_01.txt ...etc
```

But, there shouldn't be no **XCOUNT** for today's file name like **%_2015_10_07%**

I am struck at this section of code pointed below

```
DO ( IF  NOT "_%year%_%day%_%month%.txt"=="!FTRIM_%%J!"
```

My code is below

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
setlocal
SET /A MAXJ=1
SET /A J=1
echo %DATE%

set year=%date:~-4,4% 
set year=%year: =%
set month=%date:~7,2%
set month=%month: =%
set day=%date:~4,2%
set day=%day: =%

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`DIR /S /B D:\check\*.txt`) DO ( IF  NOT "_%year%_%day%_%month%.txt"=="!FTRIM_%%J!" (
  
    SET XCOUNT_!J!=%%~i
    SET FNAME_!J!=%%~ni
    SET MAXJ=!J!
    SET /A J+=1
    SET FTRIM_!nxi!=%%~nxi:~-10,10%
    
PAUSE
)
)
```

Comment: What do you believe `set \A` is doing?

Comment: I want to exclude todays extension name file from the count how can I do this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't have all of that code on the same line like that unless you tell batch where one command stops and the next command begins. Secondly, the code you have will only work on the command prompt and not in a batch file, because you need two `%`s when using `for` loop variables inside of batch files. Third, `set /a` is only used for math; use a regular `set` command when storing a string value.

Finally (and most importantly), you need delayed expansion to properly iterate your counter variable inside of your `for` loop.

This batch script should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set J=1
for /R "D:\TEST" %%I in (*.txt) do (
    set XCOUNT_!J!=%%I
    set /a J+=1
)
```

If you want to exclude a specific file from the output, wrap the `set` code in an `if` statement.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set J=1
for /R "D:\TEST" %%I in (*.txt) do (
    if not "%%~nxI"=="test.txt" (
        set XCOUNT_!J!=%%I
        set /a J+=1
    )
)
```

Comment: You can use `&` to tell batch where the command stops and the next one begins

Comment: Presumably your script sets some variables called `XCOUNT_1`, `XCOUNT_2` and so on?

Comment: Yes, in the `set XCOUNT_!J!=%%I` line.

Comment: How to show the output of path of that file  If i am trying at the end echo %XCOUNT%_%J% this is not showing the path stored in XCOUNT_1

Comment: @PrincelySurya - You can get the value of XCOUNT_1 by using `!XCOUNT_1!`

Comment: @SomethingDark well appreciated your response it worked fine but what if i want to omit a single file from the result

Comment: C:\Users\pwatson\bin>type atest.bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A J=1
SET /A MAXJ=0
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`DIR /S /B C:\Python27-32\*.exe`) DO (
    SET XCOUNT_!J!=%%~i
    SET MAXJ=!J!
    SET /A J+=1
)
SET XCOUNT

Comment: i wanted to omit a file from  the above result like test.txt shouldnt come in output of the for loop

Comment: @PrincelySurya - I have edited my answer to include single file exclusion. Also, please don't put code in comments, as it's impossible to read; edit your question instead. Also also, **never** edit somebody's answer to add a comment. _Ever._

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\pwatson\bin>type atest.bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A J=1
SET /A MAXJ=0
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`DIR /S /B C:\Python27-32\*.exe`) DO (
    SET XCOUNT_!J!=%%~i
    SET MAXJ=!J!
    SET /A J+=1
)
SET XCOUNT
```

This produces:

```
C:\Users\pwatson\bin>call atest.bat
XCOUNT_1=C:\Python27-32\python.exe
XCOUNT_10=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\t64.exe
XCOUNT_11=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\w32.exe
XCOUNT_12=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\w64.exe
XCOUNT_13=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\cli-32.exe
XCOUNT_14=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\cli-64.exe
XCOUNT_15=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\cli-arm-32.exe
XCOUNT_16=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\cli.exe
XCOUNT_17=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\gui-32.exe
XCOUNT_18=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\gui-64.exe
XCOUNT_19=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\gui-arm-32.exe
XCOUNT_2=C:\Python27-32\pythonw.exe
XCOUNT_20=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\gui.exe
XCOUNT_21=C:\Python27-32\Scripts\easy_install-2.7.exe
XCOUNT_22=C:\Python27-32\Scripts\easy_install.exe
XCOUNT_23=C:\Python27-32\Scripts\pip.exe
XCOUNT_24=C:\Python27-32\Scripts\pip2.7.exe
XCOUNT_25=C:\Python27-32\Scripts\pip2.exe
XCOUNT_3=C:\Python27-32\w9xpopen.exe
XCOUNT_4=C:\Python27-32\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-6.0.exe
XCOUNT_5=C:\Python27-32\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-7.1.exe
XCOUNT_6=C:\Python27-32\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-8.0.exe
XCOUNT_7=C:\Python27-32\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-9.0-amd64.exe
XCOUNT_8=C:\Python27-32\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-9.0.exe
XCOUNT_9=C:\Python27-32\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\t32.exe
```

Getting these back into the parent environment is another issue. I hope that dbenham might respond.

Comment: But I am struck how to iterate  with FOR loop ..XCOUNT_J this is not working  ... The only thing works is %XCOUNT_!J!% to return the value but gives error while doing operation with for loop to iterate J value

Comment: How to iterate then J value with for loop

Comment: what if i wanted to omit a result of test1.txt from the output of dir /s /b filter is not working

Comment: If you want to remove one or more lines from test1.txt, read it in a for loop and write the lines you want to a %TEMP% file.